# Could not write metadata for '/.org.eclipse.dltk.core.external.folders'

Tags: eclipse

Some day, out of the blue, my eclipse stuck.
When I reopen it, it stuck at build the workspace at 64%, and It was very slow.
A solution I found in the web is to delete the .metadeta folder, add the project one by one after that, and eclipse should recreate that folder automatically.

Not the best solution but it worked. So I did it and my eclipse work fine, but in every 15 min I get the message "Could not write metadata for '/.org.eclipse.dltk.core.external.folders'."

Log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 568 2015-11-19 10:57:32.327
!MESSAGE Could not write metadata for '/.org.eclipse.dltk.core.external.folders'.
!STACK 0
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\wamp\www\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\.org.eclipse.dltk.core.external.folders\.markers.snap (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.SafeChunkyOutputStream.<init>(SafeChunkyOutputStream.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.SafeChunkyOutputStream.<init>(SafeChunkyOutputStream.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.visitAndSnap(SaveManager.java:1745)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.visitAndSnap(SaveManager.java:1828)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.save(SaveManager.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.save(SaveManager.java:1144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.DelayedSnapshotJob.run(DelayedSnapshotJob.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I don't know how it effect the program, becuse it's run fine, but I dont like it.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try looking at the full file path and creating any folders which are missing (most likely would be the `.org.eclipse.dltk.core.external.folders` folder)

Comment: I put some considerations here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494426/could-not-write-metadata-for-myproject-d-programming-java-metadata-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to my workspace - i managed to address it by manually deleting the `$WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/.org.eclipse.dltk.core.external.folders/.location` file

In this case it looks like it would be under `C:\wamp\www/workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\.org.eclipse.dltk.core.external.folders\.location`

Comment: That's from 2011, but still useful. Althoug it did not help in my case immediately (XAMPP, Eclipse IDE), but what helped after deleting the '.location' file, was to set Project-Settings -> PHP -> Source Paths -> Include Path -> "Source" (selected the sources) -> "Apply and Close"