# Could not write metadata for '/myProject'.(D:\Programming\Java\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\myProject\.ma

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

I made this mistake with myself here in Eclipse, I searched the internet and found almost nothing on.\

Could not write metadata for '/myProject'.(D:\Programming\Java.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects\myProject.markers.snap (The system cannot find the path specified))

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are saving in your eclipse_workspace some other type of file that is not an Eclipse project. This also happens if you made that folder a Git repository. Remember that Git creates a local folder called .git to crawl your instance and then Eclipse will complain about it to you also generating the error mentioned above. I hope I have helped!